# Assign value to variable if no error

Tags: python

I get from an API a Json object.
The structure of the Json object might be different every time I run the script.

Let's say that "json_answer" is the json answer and I am looking for the value of the key 'data' that I want to store in "var", this key may not exist every time I run the script.

I would like to know if there is a shortcut for this code (one line):

```
try:
    var = json_answer['data']
except:
    var = None
```

---

**EDIT :**

Thank you for the answer, I already know about get. 
But I am looking very deep in the dictionary and I don't want to try all the "levels".

Let me clarify with this example :

```
dict = {'data':{'values':{'value':True}}}

print(dict['data']['values'].get('time', False)) # print false
print(dict['data']['values'].get('value', False)) # print True
```

I don't know in which level of the dict I might have a problem (the key exist or not). 
I just have this "PATH" ['data']['values']['value'] and if want to know if it exists or not. How can I do it with "get" ?

---

**SOLUTION :**

Based on @Ryan♦ solution and extended to JSON file that contains dict and list inside :

```
def _get(obj, keys, default=None):

    for key in keys:
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            if key not in obj:
                return default
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            if not len(obj) > key:
                return default
        else:
            return default
    obj = obj[key]
    return obj
```

Comment: Do you mean the `'data'` key won’t exist every time? And is `NULL` supposed to be `None`?

Comment: Thanks, i edited my post in order to clarify the question.

Comment: Can you do it recursively?

Comment: You can use `in` for that. `if 'data' in json_answer`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s nothing built-in, but if you write a function for it, it’s rather nice:

```
def get_path(obj, keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            obj = obj[key]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            return default

    return obj

d = {'data': {'values': {'value': True}}}

print(get_path(d, ['data', 'values', 'time'], default=False))
print(get_path(d, ['data', 'values', 'value'], default=False))
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, it works if the JSON file contains only dictionaries. Please check my update (section: Solution). Based on your function i added the "list" case.

Comment: @YassineBelmamoun: I’m not sure which update you’re referring to, but see edit?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.get()`. It will return `None` when the key is not present

```
 var = json_answer.get('data')
```

If you want to specify a default value to the `var` variable when the key is not present you can specify it as a second argument to the `.get()` function.

```
 var = json_answer.get('data', 'default_value')
```

---

Demo:

```
import json

jsonobj = json.loads('{"a": "hello"}')
print jsonobj.get('a')
print jsonobj.get('b')
print jsonobj.get('b', "BYE")
```

Output:

```
hello
None
BYE
```

---

You can try something like this for your nested case.

```
c={}
d = {'data':{'values':{'value':True}}}
var1 = d.get('aa', c).get('bb', c).get('cc', c) or None
var2 = d.get('data', c).get('values', c).get('value', c)
print var1
print var2
```

Output:

```
None
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i updated my question. Your solution works but not for my specific case.

Comment: @YassineBelmamoun Check now. You will get None when the key is not found.

Comment: It works, but it's not a pythonic solution. I think the best solution would be to use a function as described by Ryan. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @YassineBelmamoun Agree that it's more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
>>> d =  {'data': {'values': {'value': True}}}
>>> d.get('data', {}).get('values', {}).get('time', False)
False
>>> d.get('data', {}).get('values', {}).get('value', False)
True
```

Comment: It works, but it's not a pythonic solution. I think the best solution would be to use a function as described by Ryan since there is nothing built-in. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why do you think it's not a Pythonic solution?

Comment: I would like to avoid using three time the function "get" and repeat the definition of the default value. Thank you very much for your help.